# PHP getimagesize is not working when is called from a function in function.php (Wordpress)?

Tags: wordpress, function, getimagesize

PHP getimagesize is not working when is called from a function in `function.php`.

**function.php:**

```
<?php

    // Theme Options
    require_once(TEMPLATEPATH . '/functions/admin-menu.php');

    add_action('wp_head', 'theme_options', 'get_image_size');

    function theme_options() {
        // Initiate Theme Options
        $options = get_option('plugin_options');

        // If a logo image was uploaded then remove text from site title
        if ($options['logo'] != NULL)
            $remove_text = '-9999px';

        else
            $remove_text = 0;

        ?><style>
        body {
            background-color: <?php echo $options['color_scheme']; ?>
        }

        #header h1 a {
            background: url(<?php echo $options['logo']; ?>) no-repeat scroll 0 0;
            text-indent: <?php echo $remove_text; ?>;
        }
        </style><?php
    }

    function get_image_size() {

        list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize($options['logo']);

        echo "Image width " .$width;
        echo "<BR>";
        echo "Image height " .$height;
        echo "<BR>";

        var_dump($width);
        var_dump($heigt);
    }
```

`$options['logo']` is returning `http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2010/12/logo4.png` so the image is being displayed.

I also did `var_dump` to `$width` and `$height` but they didn't show up.

Any suggestions?

**EDIT: I pasted the full code of `functions.php`.  `$options['logo']` works perfectly in the `theme_option` function so I don't know why it doesn't work in the `get_image_size` function.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out how to fix it (separating the functions into different `add_action` statements):

```
add_action('wp_head', 'theme_options');

function theme_options { 
    ...
}

add_action('wp_head', 'get_image_size');

function get_image_size { 
    ...
}
```

The `add_action` only allows one function?

What was the problem?

Comment: This was the problem:  <?php add_action( $tag, $function_to_add, $priority, $accepted_args ); ?> http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action. I can only add one action, the rest are other statements.

Answer (score 1):

`$options['logo']` is undefined in your code. If it is defined outside of your function, it is not by default available inside of your function.

Please enable error reporting using `ini_set('display_errors', 1)` and `error_reporting(E_ALL)`, when developing. This will make sure any errors are reported.

Comment: I have error_reporting and display_errors turned on in my php.ini (and there's no errors). $options['logo'] works fine in the function above `get_image_size` (check my new EDIT).

Answer (score 0):

I you do not see any error messages, turn up [error_reporting](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting) and [display_errors](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors).

> $options['logo'] works perfectly in
>   the theme_option function so I don't
>   know why it doesn't work in the
>   get_image_size function.

As @Sjoerd said: `$options` is not defined in function `get_image_size`. It is only defined in function `theme_options`. That's what functions are about, they are a black box that know about their environment only from the arguments they receive. If you want to make the options visible in function `get_image_size`, you have to *Initiate Theme Options* in that function as well.

Comment: I have error_reporting and display_errors turned on and I don't see anything (check my new EDIT).